Does defining a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ as a set of ordered pairs make sense?
In high school functions were treated variously as a machine with inputs and outputs or as a rule for creating an output for any input. But in university classes like abstract algebra and analysis, they were defined as a set of ordered pairs.
How does the latter definition work without also a rule since there would have to be an infinite such list?

You can think of the set of pairs as the rule: $f(a)=b$ if and only if $(a,b)$ is a pair in the set.

In mathematics we allow ourselves to write down infinite lists!

@QiaochuYuan: sounds time consuming.

To be a little more precise, we allow ourselves to write down an infinite list by providing a rule that tells us whether a particular ordered pair is or is not in the list.  Example:  ${(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2) \mid y=x^2 }$.

But there need not be a rule.  The first that comes to mind is the proof that two countable dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic, where you are just told at each stage "pick any number that fits to make the function".  Of course, you have to argue that you don't run out so it always works, but there is no rule.

In ZFC every object needs to be a set. In high school the function is defined as a "machine", which is sufficient to handle high school maths. But to study serious maths, we need the axiomatic set theory, in which every object should be viewed as a set, including functions, real numbers (viewed as sets via Dedekind cuts), etc.

Usually, in mathematics, a function from a set $A$ to a set $B$, denoted $f:A\rightarrow B$ is defined as a special kind of binary  relation.
A binary relation over sets $A$ and $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$. That is, it is a collection of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A,$ and $b\in B$
A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a binary relation over $A$ and $B$ satisfying the property that if $(a,b_1)\in f$ and $(a,b_2)\in f$ then $b_1=b_2$. You will recognize this as the familiar "vertical line test" from highschool. In this case we can unambiguously define $f(a):=b$.
Now, to bring this definition back into agreement with the high school notion of a function as a machine, think of the function $f$ as the machine which takes input $a$ and outputs $f(a)$. Here we are assuming that $f$ is already defined as a binary relation. This may sound overly reductive, but, there it is.
Similarly, if we already have the function defined as a binary relation, and we want to think of it as a "rule of assignment", then it is just the rule which assigns $f(a)$ to $a$. We often write this as $$a \mapsto f(a)$$
again, this may sound overly reductive or simple, but this is why we use the precise definition in mathematics. The high school "definitions" should really be thought of as heuristics, not truly dfinitions.
